# How to compare current date and date from line in txt file?

Tags: bash

I want to check when week left before the certificate expires for our users on Openvpn server. On server installed Centos 6.7. I can export enddate and subject from all .crt to txt file with the command

```
openssl x509 -subject -enddate -noout -in filename
```

in format:

```
subject= /C=Country/ST=ca/L=City/O=company/OU=uit/CN=user/emailAddress=email
notAfter=Oct  8 13:48:27 2020 GMT
```

Current date on server in format - `Wed May 25 10:03:06 MSK 2016`
How to compare current date and date in line `notAfter` in txt file, and if left week or less before the certificate expires, make the txt file with name of user from the `subject` line with text `True`?

Comment: Valid question, perhaps; however, you're just asking for someone to do **all** the work *for* you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert the date string to epoch time, which is counted in seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and compare the number of seconds.

To get the current date in seconds, do:

```
[jenny@finch ~]$ date +%s
1464162079
```

To get the date from the date string above, do

```
[jenny@finch ~]$ date -d 'Oct 8 13:48:27 2020 GMT'  +%s
1602164907
```

A week is 604800 seconds, so check whether the difference between the two times is less than that.